# display manager issue - Screen/GUI loads layer by layer in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, display, lightdm, gui

Recently I got notification from software updater that update is available and instead of using `apt-get upgrade` I just updated from software updater, after reboot the screen was flickering continuously.

To solve that I removed lightdm and nvidia components with:

```
apt-get remove nvidia*
apt-get purge lightdm
```

and reinstalled and reconfigured:

```
apt-get install lightdm
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and restarted the pc, and now all GUI components are loading in a layered manner which is lagging too much-causing delay of about 3 to 5 seconds to load layer of the complete window as in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dDCe8f1Hho&feature=youtu.be) link.

I tried to again reinstall but more I dig it stops display manager to load at all and upon reinstalling it throws me to either screen flickering or the GUI component issue as in the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dDCe8f1Hho&feature=youtu.be).

I have already followed these instructions:
1. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

> You can get to a text terminal using `alt-ctrl-F1`.
>   Check the LightDM logs in `/var/log/lightdm`.
>   Stop LightDM with `sudo stop lightdm`.
>   You can try LightDM again with `sudo start lightdm`.
>   You can set the default display manager by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.
>   Check your system is up to date, especially video drivers.

2. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384467